# multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]-warning error

Tags: c

*[this is the code i want to print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrQvf.png)*
`printf("%d %c",97,'97');`

*[this warning i get when i compile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPumW.png)*
`|warning: multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]`

*[this what out put i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5bNZ.png)*
`output`

**i want to print the 97 ascii value which is a. but compiler give me that warning . help me out please.**

Comment: Try `printf("%d %c",97,97);`

Comment: Or `printf("%d %c",'a','a');`

Comment: first of all thank you for assist me @WhozCraig . the out put is fine now.

Comment: first of all thank you for assist me @WeatherVane . yes the code is work properly now.